# How do you return all values of an array in Lua?

Tags: arrays, lua

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm a fairly inexperienced programmer.

I'm trying to return all values within an array using Lua. I can return individual elements by calling their index (ex. read_data[2]) but since the number of elements in the array is variable, I cannot simply type this out. My code:

```
function readformatEvent()

local read_data = {}
local duplicate
local unique_data = {}

for i=1,16 do
    read_data[i] = readResult(i):readData()
end

for i=1,16 do
    duplicate = 0

    for j=(i+1),15 do
        if read_data[i] == read_data[j] then
            duplicate = 1
        end
    end

    if duplicate == 0 then
        unique_data[i] = read_data[i]
    end
end

return unique_data

end
```

unique_data is an array consisting of unique values from the array read_data. read_data can consist of 1 to 16 elements. Being able to see the full array would help me continue to craft the code as a troubleshooting technique.

Thank you,

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you mean by returning the values from the array. Are you trying to return the elements of the array as Lua multiple-return-values?

Comment: Yes, I would like the function readformatEvent() to return each individual element of the array 'unique_data' in a list

Comment: What do you mean "in a list"? Do you mean like how Lua can return multiple values like `return 5, 3, 5`? Or do you mean returning a *single value* which is a list of other values, like `return {5, 3, 5}`?

Comment: I think I mean returning a single value which is a list of other values such as `return {5, 3, 5}`

I'd like to return everything contained within 'unique_data' as a single value that happens to be a list

Comment: That's what `unique_data` *is already*. Well, except for what Francisco pointed out in his answer, that you're not inserting the elements into the array properly. Outside of that, `unique_data` is exactly what you want.

Comment: Hmm even after I cut out everything after the first FOR loop, and return 'read_data', I still get nothing back. But I can return individual elements of 'read_data' and they will appear as expected.

Comment: How are you printing the data? If the array has "holes" in it (which will happen if `duplicate == 0`) you will need to use `pairs` as the returned object won't be an array.

Comment: @JMR: At this point, the only way we can know what you're talking about is if you post the code that's actually trying to use the return value.

Comment: @colonelthirtytwo the data is being printed as an ASCII string. I see what you mean about the holes. I will look into `pairs`

Comment: @nicolbolas I see. I think that may be my problem - I don't have access to the code trying to return the value. I can only edit the function.

Comment: @JMR: ... what? If the code that you're returning a value to doesn't know that you're returning an array, then there's no way to return an array. The receiver has to process arrays differently from processing a single value. If it isn't written to do that, then it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for walking me through this. It sounds like I was thinking about it the correct way but I'm constrained by the system I'm working within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short example of what you could do:

```
-- some example table
t = {1,2,4,5,1,2,7,8,5,4,9,3}

-- for every value v in t
for k,v in pairs(t) do

  -- check v vs all remaining values in t
  for m,w in pairs(t) do
    -- but not vs v itself
    if k ~= m then
      -- remove any non unique values from t
      if w == v then
        t[m] = nil
        t[k] = nil
      end
    end
  end
end

-- print the result
for k,v in pairs(t) do
  print(v)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Your example of using pairs was the key to unlocking this problem. Initially I followed your instruction but tried to use `ipairs` and it didn't work - none of the duplicates were removed. Then when I used `pairs` it worked flawlessly. I guess I don't fully understand why `ipairs` didn't work but thanks regardless.

Comment: @JMR ipairs iterates over the table elements t[1], t[2], t[3] and so on. It always starts at 1 and stops when the first element is nil. So you can't have any gaps in your table! Non-numeric keys will be ignored.
pairs instead iterates over all table elements. No matter what key they have.

Comment: Excellent explanation! So in this case when we replace one of the table values with nil, that will essentially prevent ipairs from checking the rest of the table for duplicates?

Comment: yes. whereas pairs will check every table element that is left. but you don't have a guarateed order.
so what I do is I check every value. if it is not unique I will delete all duplicates and the value itself. when I run over the table next time it will have 1 set of duplicates less.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. Here is the code that ended up working. I'm sure it's not efficient, but I'm getting the correct output now.

```
function readformatEvent()

function readformatEvent()

local read_data = {}
local unique_data = {}
local count = 1
local output = ""
local codes = readResult():readCount()

--create array from captured read data

for i=1,16 do
    read_data[i] = readResult(i):readData()
end

--turn 2nd duplicate in the array into a nil value

for k,v in pairs(read_data) do

    for m,w in pairs(read_data) do

        if k ~= m then

            if w == v then
                read_data[m] = nil
            end
        end
    end
end

--remove the nils from the array

for i=1,16 do
    if read_data[i] ~= nil then
        unique_data[count] = read_data[i]
        count = count+1
    end
end

--output unique values in correct format

if count == 12 and codes == 16 then
    count = count - 1
else
    count = count - 2
end

for i=1,count-1 do
    output = output..unique_data[i]..", "
end

return output..unique_data[count]


end
```

Comment: you can use table.insert(unique_data, read_data[i]) in your second last for loop. This will append read_data[i] to the table so you don't have to count the non-nil elements.

#unique_data will give you the number of elements in unique_data. (it will count from 1 to the until it hits the first nil. So again be careful with gaps).   For t = {1,2,nil,4}, #t will return 2!

Comment: That definitely would have been helpful. My last hurdle was the count variable itself. It seemed to be counting +1 extra increment during certain situations, yet not others. I couldn't figure out what was causing it but I came up with a work-around. I will use table.insert now.

Comment: I changed the second for loop and used `table.insert(unique_data, read_data[i])` and it worked like a charm. I was still having trouble with #unique_data though. It seemed to be reaching a higher value than the true number of unique data entries when I was using it in the final for loop. This was the same problem I was having with the count variable.